# Disable title filter when editing questions

Tags: feature-request, editor

I just came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45449352/1879699) that had a dead link in it. I had tried to edit the question but the system didn't accept the change:

[image]

Since I haven't changed the title it makes little to no sense to warn me (as the editor) that the title is violating rules.

I would like to suggest to disable the title filter when the title hasn't changed during an edit.

Comment: The problem is _code_ in the title. If you change that to _classes_ I think you should be able to edit it.

Comment: Thank you Erik, that worked well. Question still stand if it's an edit and the title hasn't changed, why give out the warning at all? That's just confusing people. ;)

Comment: Yup, but [the entire title filter is controversial and confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112944/369403). As this is behaving by design and has been previously reported, I've suggested a duplicate, but if you rewrite it to a feature request (disable the title filter when editing questions and not touching the title) that might gain some traction. However, some users think these titles should be improved when editing other things, as an edit should address all flaws in a post.

Comment: OK Erik, I changed it into a feature request.